# XStream delete unwanted fields of a collection

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, xstream

I have an object "Role" which can contain several "Privileges", which are objects too. Now, when i try to serialize Role with Xstream my xml looks like this:

```
  <role>
    <roleName>Administrator</roleName>
    <privileges class="org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet">
      <set>
        <privilege>
          <privilegeId>1001</privilegeId>
          <privilegeName>Admin Privilege</privilegeName>
          <privilegeKey>Admin</privilegeKey>
        </privilege>
      </set>
      <initialized>true</initialized>
      <owner class="role" reference="../.."/>
      <cachedSize>-1</cachedSize>
      <rolemodel.valueobject.Role.privileges</role>
      <key class="int">3</key>
      <dirty>false</dirty>
      <storedSnapshot class="map">
        <entry>
          <privilege reference="../../../set/privilege"/>
          <privilege reference="../../../set/privilege"/>
        </entry>
      </storedSnapshot>
    </privileges>
  </role>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
  <role>
    <roleName>Administrator</roleName>
    <privileges>
          <privilegeId>1001</privilegeId>
          <privilegeName>Admin Privilege</privilegeName>
          <privilegeKey>Admin</privilegeKey>
    </privileges>
  </role>
```

How can i omit/delete/not include all those additional fields? Seems like they are "utility" fields, added by hibernate, as i haven't declared them in my hbm.xml.
I already tried omitting them, adding Privileges collection as implicit and other things i found on XStream page.

**Edit**
I failed to create XSLT template as suggested below, but found that custom converter is really good and simple tool to do this job. Check the help page here  - http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html.
And here's my marshal method:

```
public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
                    MarshallingContext context) {
    Role role = (Role) value;
    writer.startNode("roleId");
    writer.setValue(role.getRoleId().toString());
    writer.endNode();
    writer.startNode("roleName");
    writer.setValue(role.getRoleName());
    writer.endNode();
    writer.startNode("privileges");
    for (Privilege privilege : role.getPrivileges()){
        writer.startNode("privilege");
        writer.setValue(privilege.getPrivilegeName());
        writer.endNode();
    }
    writer.endNode();
}
```

And xml it produces:

```
  <role>
    <roleId>3</roleId>
    <roleName>Web Administrator</roleName>
    <privileges>
      <privilege>Web Access</privilege>
    </privileges>
  </role>
```